# What happens to the charge that is introduced at the centre of a spherical conducting shell?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conformal-field-theory

I have seen similar questions here but haven't understood this:

If we introduce a charge *+Q* inside a spherical conducting shell,  this charge attracts an equal negative charge i.e. electrons towards the inside of the shell, so as the electrons are pulled away from the atoms of the metal constituting the shell a charge *+Q* is induced on the outside of the shell.

So there are 3 charges at work here, aren't there?    A *+Q* charge at the centre of the spherical shell, a *+Q* on the outside *surface* of the shell and a *-Q* charge on the inside *surface* of the shell.

So, shouldn't the net charge *enclosed* by the shell be *+Q* (which is the charge at the centre), it hasn't disappeared somewhere has it?

If so, then why, when calculating the electric field inside the shell using Gauss' Law, do we take the net charge enclosed by the shell to be zero (and so, then proceed to calculate the electric field inside to be zero) ?

I would really like if someone could help me here.

Comment: @MrReality...Look , you yourself have said that electric field intensir6inside is zero.That is , the induced positive charge outside has nothing to do with the interior intensity...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384868/flux-in-spherical-cavity Look here...

Comment: @NehalSamee, what do you mean? What I asked here is why do we take the charge enclosed by a Gaussian surface **inside** a spherical conducting shell to be zero, when in fact we have introduced a charge at the centre of the shell ? I didn't say the induced charges at the inside and outside surfaces of the shell have anything to do in the electric field inside..

Comment: @NehalSamee, so (from the link you provided I gather) we don't take the charge enclosed by the sphere in the case to be zero?

Comment: @MrReality...The electric field depends on the Gaussian surface you consider...If you take the Gaussian surface in the interior surface , you get the net charge zero inside...You can watch out the lecture of Walter Lewin in You Tube...

Comment: @MrReality...There is a charge at the center...But you can't say that ,remaining outside ,whether the charge is in the surface or at the centre. Electric field intensity is still zero inside (only in case of hollow sphere)...

Comment: "There is a charge at the center...But you can't say that ,remaining outside ,whether the charge is in the surface or at the centre" - Why can't I? In the link you gave, it's stated that if we place a charge at the centre, *it is at the centre*, it doesn't disappear, it just induces charges on the inside (-Q) and outside (+Q) surfaces of the shell.  "Electric field intensity is still zero inside (only in case of hollow sphere)..."  -  Again from the link you gave, I've gathered that in the scenario I'm talking about, the electric field inside the shell or outside the shell is *Not* zero ..

Comment: .. rather the electric field on the surface of the shell is zero. Are you sure you aren't thinking of something else here?

Comment: @MrReality...Keeping a charge at centre is equivalent to keeping on surface as long as you are outside...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72994/discussion-between-mr-reality-and-nehal-samee).

Comment: *"If so, then why, when calculating the electric field inside the shell using Gauss' Law, do we take the net charge enclosed by the shell to be zero (and so, then proceed to calculate the electric field inside to be zero) ?"*.  We do not. For an envelope inside the shell, charge ***is*** $Q$ and electrical field is ***not*** zero.